# Jquery find where id=myid

Tags: jquery, search, if-statement, find

Need to check element with `myid`  exist or not.

This is some pseudocode:

```
if (myid exists)
{ 
    //do something.
}
else
{
    //do something else.
}
```

How would I do this in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a jQuery ID selector and the `.length` property:

```
if( $( '#myId' ).length > 0 ) {
  // id exists
} else {
  // id does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with

```
if( $('#myid').length) ){ // element exists }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length`:

```
if($("#myid").length) {
    //true
    do something.  
} else {
    //false
    do something else.  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if ($("#" + myid).length) {
    // exists
} else {
    // doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#" + id).length > 0) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#myid").length == 0) {
   do something else //does not exist
} else {
   do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#" + myid).length > 0) {

}
```

or   simply

```
if($("#" + myid).length) {


 }
```